# Why Redux store doesn't update component on iOS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a state in Redux store, for example: `footerView: { show: true }` in my React app.
I'm updating it in my function in component (on click function), and some other components need to be updated (depending on the value from store)

I get updates in the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {...}, [footerView]);
```

It **works** on all devices, but doesn't work on iOS. The component isn't updated. What is the problem?

Comment: I guess the problem caused by other reasons.

Comment: @zynkn what could be the problem?

Comment: It depends on your code.

Comment: @zynkn should there be a special implementation for the iOS?